# Javascript array displaying all values

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello People here is my code,

```
function send()
{
  var param_count=document.getElementsByName('eqt_param[]');

  for (var i=0; i<param_count.length; i++)
  {
    var test=param_count[i].value;  
    var param_value='Eqt_Param'+i+'='+test;

    alert(param_value);
  }
}
```

if i alert i get  `"Eqt_Param0=4.00"` then `"Eqt_Param1=3.00"` but i want to alert at once output should be something like  `"Eqt_Param0=4.00,Eqt_Param1=3.00 "`  after alerting this way i also want to remove the `','` in between how to fix this?

Comment: put your html code part. it will be useful

Comment: Not quite sure what your problem is. There is no array in your code... do you want to use one? If yes, where are you stuck? I recommend to read the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object) to learn the basics about arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean this:

```
function send()
{
  var param_count=document.getElementsByName('eqt_param[]');
  var values = [];
  for (var i=0; i<param_count.length; i++)
  {
    values.push('Eqt_Param'+i+'='+param_count[i].value)
  }
  alert(values.join(', '));
}
```

Comment: I edited the code: Use literals instead of objects. Variables `test` and `param_value` are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
function send()
{
  var tempArray=[]; 
  var param_count=document.getElementsByName('eqt_param[]');

  for (var i=0; i<param_count.length; i++)
  {
     var test=param_count[i].value;  
     var param_value +='Eqt_Param'+i+'='+test;
     tempArray.push(param_value)

  }

    alert(tempArray.join(','));  //to join with ','
    var joinedstr=tempArray.join(',');
    var finalArray= joinedstr.split(',');  //to split with ','
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array` has some useful functions to make your life easier, `forEach` and `join`.

```
function send()
{
  var toPrint = []
  document.getElementsByName('eqt_param[]').forEach( function(el, idx) {
    toPrint.append('Eqt_Param'+idx+'='+x.value);
  }
  alert(toPrint.join(', '));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need an array for that:

```
alert((function(array, string, _i, _len) {
    for(; _i < _len; _i++)
        string += 'Eqt_Param' + _i + ' = '+ array[_i].value + ", ";
    return string.substr(0, string.length -2);
    } (document.getElementsByName('eqt_param[]'), "", 0, document.getElementsByName('eqt_param[]').length)));
```